# Bash Assign variable from command with default value

Tags: bash

If you have:

```
val="bar"
```

Is there easier way of doing the following:

```
# get value from foo
result=`foo boom baz`

# if we have non falsy value from foo, store it in val:

if [ $result ] ; then
  val=$result
fi

#else val remains at "bar"
```

Basically I am looking for something equivalent to the following C statement:

`val=foo() || val;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
val="bar"

result=$(foo boom baz)
val=${result:-$val}       # Assign result if not empty, otherwise val
                          # similar to C  val = *result ? result : val;

echo "val is now $val"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the return code from `foo` is a valid indication of whether it will have output something to fill `result` you can use:

```
if result=`foo boom baz`; then
  val=$result
fi
```

You could also just combine the two original lines (though I don't recommend this):

```
if result=`foo boom baz`; [ $result ] ; then
  val=$result
fi
```

Comment: That technique isn't used often enough, but it's not what was asked for here -- the `if` is testing the `foo` _return code_.  `$result` can easily be non-empty.  On the other hand, of course, this might be what OP was trying to ask for in the first place ...

Comment: @jthill There's a reason I started with "Assuming" here. The first option only works given that assumption. The second doesn't require it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it slightly differently to be more explicit about the default value:

```
default=bar
val=$(foo boom baz)
: ${val:="$default"}      # use the : command to allow side effects to occur
echo "val is now: $val"
```

Testing: with no `foo`

```
val is now: bar
```

Testing: with `foo() { echo qux; }`

```
val is now: qux
```

Comment: But the requirement is that I would need the variable that was initially assigned the value "bar" to be the one that conditionally holds the result of `foo()`. So at the end of your solution I would need to do `default=$val`.

Comment: Then "that other guy" truly has your answer.